# Symfony2 doctrine exception in persisting OneToMany entities

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I configure this entities:

MarketMain:

```
class MarketMain
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketLanguage", mappedBy="marketMain", indexBy="langId", cascade="all", orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $marketLanguage;
}
```

MarketLanguage:

```
    class MarketLanguage
    {    
        /**
         * @var \Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketMain
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketMain", inversedBy="marketLanguage")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="market_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $marketMain;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(name="lang_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         */
        private $langId = 1;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
         */
        private $name;
    }
```

And I want to save entity like this:

```
...........
    $form = $this->createForm(new MarketMainType(), new MarketMain());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $marketFormData = $form->getData();

    $em->persist($marketFormData);
    $em->flush($marketFormData);

    foreach ($marketFormData->getMarketLanguage() as $market_language)
    {
             $market_language->setName("My market name");
             $market_language->setMarketMain($marketFormData);
             $em->persist($market_language);
    }

    $em->flush();
```

Than I get this error:

> Entity of type Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketLanguage is missing an
>   assigned ID for field 'marketMain'. The identifier generation strategy
>   for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before
>   EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated
>   identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping
>   accordingly.

If I trying to do `$marketFormData` persist after foreach statment I get this error:

> Entity of type Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketLanguage has identity
>   through a foreign entity Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketMain, however
>   this entity has no identity itself. You have to call
>   EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an
>   identifier was generated before trying to persist
>   'Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketLanguage'. In case of Post Insert ID
>   Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this
>   means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist
>   operations.

I know that If I try to persist `$marketFormData` before loop doctrine does not know the releated `$marketLanguage` references, but if I set persist after the foreach it says taht I have first persist parent entity. So I tried this code and it worked:

```
...........
    $form = $this->createForm(new MarketMainType(), new MarketMain());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $marketFormData = $form->getData();

    $market_languages = $marketFormData->getMarketLanguage();

    $marketFormData->setMarketLanguage(null);
    $em->persist($marketFormData);
    $em->flush($marketFormData);

    $marketFormData->setMarketLanguage($market_languages);
    foreach ($marketFormData->getMarketLanguage() as $market_language)
    {
             $market_language->setName("My market name");
             $market_language->setMarketMain($marketFormData);
             $em->persist($market_language);
    }

    $em->flush();
```

But it is only way to persist related entities? To clone it set to null, persist parent entity, and then set it back, add references and flush all. I think I have missed something here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your entities is mapped wrong. The entity must have an annotation about ID and another to relation.

And also, when you don't have a primary key with autoincrement, it is necessary declare the class constructor, passing both values as mentioned in http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

It should look like this:

```
class MarketLanguage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="market_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $marketId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="lang_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $langId = 1;

    /**
     * @var \Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketMain
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketMain", inversedBy="marketLanguage")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="market_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $marketMain;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    public function __construct($marketId, $langId) {
        $this->marketId = $marketId;
        $this->langId = $langId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try remove flush($marketFormData) ?:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MarketMainType(),$marketMain);
$form->handleRequest($request);
$marketFormData = $form->getData();

$em->persist($marketFormData);
// $em->flush($marketFormData); // remove that flush

foreach ($marketFormData->getMarketLanguage() as $market_language)
{
         $market_language->setName("My market name");
         $market_language->setMarketMain($marketMain);
         $em->persist($market_language);
}

$em->flush();
```

maybe problem is that you are trying flush $marketFormData which contains MarketLanguages which are not persised ? Not sure am i right, didn't tested this.

EDIT maybe this work:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MarketMainType(), new MarketMain());
$form->handleRequest($request);
$marketFormData = $form->getData();

foreach ($marketFormData->getMarketLanguage() as $market_language)
{
         $market_language->setName("My market name");
         $market_language->setMarketMain($marketMain);
}

$em->persist($marketFormData);
$em->flush($marketFormData);
```

Comment: Yes I tried It and I got same error: Entity of type Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketLanguage is missing an assigned ID for field 'marketMain'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

Comment: And StackTrace show that error occurs at first persist.

Comment: I do not show $marketMain variable because it is just Entity form database, its all good to this variable I guarantee that.

Comment: @DonatasVeikutis so maybe it should be `$em->persist($marketMain);` against `$em->persist($marketFormData);` i`m guessing, have no idea now why it doesn't work:)

Comment: No if you know how form builder works I have to add new MarketMain() entity to it for form save from html form.

Comment: No, i get the second error:
Entity of type Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketLanguage has identity through a foreign entity Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketMain, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier was generated before trying to persist 'Acme\CMSBundle\Entity\MarketLanguage'. In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations.